# template if:true with get variable is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, template, getter

I have a custom part of code that I want to be displayed based on a custom logic

cmp:

```
<template if:true={myvar}>
    <!-- custom code -->
</template>
```

js:

```
@track data;

 get myvar(){
     //this is just a test
     let result = (data.first && !data.second && data.third.includes('test'));
     console.log('result', result);
     return result;
 }
```

The issue is that my `console.log()` is printing me `true` but I'm unable to see code placed inside my template

Do I need to set result on a `@track` attribute or is there something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might [help](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/js_props_boolean).

> Boolean attributes on standard HTML Elements are set to true by adding
>   the attribute to the element. The absence of the attribute defaults
>   the attribute to false. Therefore, **the default value of an attribute
>   is always false.** Lightning web components use the same principle for
>   boolean properties.

Comment: So do I need to set it as `@track` or? Cause I don't understand which is the proper way to achieve this even after checking documentation.

Comment: Since you are using custom logic and expecting the propery value to change, you need to `@track` it, if you are exposing your property to a parent component, you should use `@api`

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!

Comment: @molinet no problem, when you are not using any decorators, your property becomes `private` and no changes of that property will be reflected on the html template, if changed.